# Quartz : Undefined symbols when building for x86_64 architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I've create a console project and add Quartz.Framework, QuartzCore.Framework into my app.

But during linking it gives following errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGColorCreateGenericRGB", referenced from:
      GifFlippingBook::GifFlippingBookCreator::CreateGifFlippingBook(int, int, double, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string) in main.o
  "_CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename", referenced from:
      GifFlippingBook::GifFlippingBookCreator::CreateGifFlippingBook(int, int, double, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string) in main.o
  "_CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider", referenced from:
      GifFlippingBook::GifFlippingBookCreator::CreateGifFlippingBook(int, int, double, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, int, std::string, std::string, std::string) in main.o
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah found the answer on my own

CoreGraphics framework is part of ApplicationServices.Framework so I just need to add it into linking libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to add the CoreGraphics framework.

Comment: It doesn't show up in available frameworks in Xcode, isn't that embedded into Quartz Framework ?

Comment: I'm creating pure Mac OS X project when I switch the Base SDK to iOS it shows up. Why the framework does not showup when I set it to Mac OS X